# How do I install Google Earth Pro on 14.04?

Tags: permissions, google-earth

I signed myself up for a license to use Google Earth Pro and downloaded the GoogleEarthLinux.bin file.

Tried to install it using `sudo sh GoogleEarthLinux.bin` from terminal. This resulted in:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing Google Earth for GNU/Linux 6.0.3.2197.............................................................................................
setup.data/bin/Linux/amd64/setup.gtk2: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

loki_setup: Suspect size value for option option
loki_setup: Suspect size value for option option
loki_setup: Suspect size value for option option
Installing mimetypes...
Installing desktop menu entries...
Installing desktop icon...
/usr/local/sbin/googleearth: 18: exec: ./googleearth-bin: not found
nick@his-computer:~/Desktop$ googleearth
/usr/local/sbin/googleearth: 18: exec: ./googleearth-bin: not found
```

Then I tried:

```
$ wget http://dl.google.com/earth/client/current/GoogleEarthLinux.bin && chmod +x GoogleEarthLinux.bin && ./GoogleEarthLinux.bin

--2015-01-30 15:31:15--  http://dl.google.com/earth/client/current/GoogleEarthLinux.bin
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 74.125.136.93, 74.125.136.190, 74.125.136.136, ...
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|74.125.136.93|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 33688483 (32M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘GoogleEarthLinux.bin’
100%[======================================>] 33.688.483  3,64MB/s   in 8,7s   
2015-01-30 15:31:24 (3,70 MB/s) - ‘GoogleEarthLinux.bin’ saved [33688483/33688483]

Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing Google Earth for GNU/Linux 6.0.3.2197.............................................................................................
setup.data/bin/Linux/amd64/setup.gtk2: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load module "liboverlay-scrollbar.so": liboverlay-scrollbar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load module "libunity-gtk-module.so": libunity-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
loki_setup: Suspect size value for option option
loki_setup: Suspect size value for option option
Installing mimetypes...
Installing desktop menu entries...
Installing desktop icon...

chmod: changing permissions of ‘/home/nick/Desktop/Google-googleearth.desktop’: Operation not permitted
/home/nick/googleearth: 18: exec: ./googleearth-bin: not found
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Your system is missing the file `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0`, which is part of the package `libgtk2.0-0`. You need to install that first: `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0`.

Comment: I tried, but system says it's allready installed.

Comment: Does [this discussion](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/install-google-earth-in-ubuntu-1404.html) apply to your setup?

Answer (score 3):

I can't say this will work for everyone obviously but I did get Google Earth PRO to launch on Ubuntu 14.04 after following a few suggestions already posted so thought I'd summarize. In the end not all of this seems like it was necessary but just saying what I did in case some part is actually necessary.

First you can download the GoogleEarth Pro binary installer

When I first ran the installer GoogleEarthLinux.bin it complained it couldn't find some libraries and refused to install at all. So then I followed the advice at the following link to install the i386 binaries, but not the google-earth deb package:

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/install-google-earth-in-ubuntu-1404.html

When running the GoogleEarthLinux.bin installer it now installed but complained about 3 missing libraries (libxml2.so.2, liboverlay-scrollbar.so & libunity-gtk-module.so). Progress but the binary still wouldn't launch ('googleearth-bin': No such file or directory').

So then I installed libglide3:i386 (just reported as suggested when installing all the other libraries above), libxml2:i386 & unity-gtk2-module:i386. Tried installing overlay-scrollbar:i386 package but it apparently doesn't exist. Ran the GoogleEarthLinux.bin installer again. Installer reported overlay-scrollbar missing (expected) and a bunch of GTK-Warning's, but the installer completed again...still no love launching googleearth-bin.

So lastly I installed lsb-core as recommended by another answer above & this link:

http://www.coyotus.com/viewtopic.php?pid=6396#p6396

And THAT finally resulted in Google earth launching. To summarize I really just think the following two actions 'fixed' my problem (I don't really think the other installations I did likely mattered but your mileage may vary).

Install the i386 packages according to the first link then lsb-core according to the second link.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry to disappoint, but Google Earth Pro is not available for linux btw...

Comment: I have to agree with this answer, I downloaded Google Earth (the so-called Pro link for Linux), but it only installed Google Earth :-(

Comment: I just installed Google Earth Pro on Linux, and got the correct version. Whatever the problem was, it looks like it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth does not run in a true 64 bit mode - you need to install several 32 bit libraries to make it work.

Enter the commands

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386 \
libglu1-mesa:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libxext6:i386 \
libxrender1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 lsb-core
```

and you will go a long way to solving your problems.  A good deal of information about this can be found at [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleEarth)

Comment: Thank you. I followed every word from the link you provided. Downloaded the `.deb` file instead of the `.bin`. Alas, now I'm stuck with the install in the Ubuntu Software Center with the output: Dependency is not satisfiable `ia32-libs`

Comment: [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/install-google-earth-in-ubuntu-1404.html) has a good link on installation in Ubuntu 14.04 (and 14.10) - the text is far too long to summarize in comments.

Comment: Did google released google earth pro for linux?

Comment: Well, on the [google website](http://www.google.com/intl/en/earth/download/gep/agree.html) it does indicate that system requirements are Windows or Mac

Comment: If all else fails I'll try with wine.

Answer (score 1):

In the same situation, [this](http://www.coyotus.com/viewtopic.php?pid=6396#p6396) worked for me:  `sudo apt-get install lsb-core`

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that allready. lsb-core is allready the most recent version